# searching for an item then displaying an error with if else

Tags: python

this is a part of my code. I have no idea why the If and elif aren't working. if i remove them my code works perfectly. I have the same thing in an other code where it works, the only thing different in this code is that i have 2 sys.argv. When i look at essaie it is getting the value 3. I want to make sure that if sys.argv 2 is missing to print a message. Any tip?

This code import a txt, then make a list then search into it then display the written result.

```
exemple of list:
pomme: 23
banana: 10
orange: 12
```

---

```
exemple of input

item.py data1.txt pomme
```

---

```
def recherche(texte, item, essaie):
    while True:
        if len(essaie) > 3:
            print("Un seul argument est attendu, soit le nom du fichier à traiter")
            sys.exit()
        elif len(essaie) < 3:
            print("Il faut préciser le nom du fichier à traiter")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            resultat = [s for s in ligne(texte) if item in s] #finding the word in lines
            resultat2 = str(resultat)
            resultat3 = resultat2.strip("[']")
            print(resultat3)
            sys.exit()

def main(): 
    essaie = sys.argv
    entree = sys.argv[1]
    item = sys.argv[2]
    choix = str(entree)
    texte = choix.strip("[']")
    recherche(texte, item, essaie)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

The output im getting if i object to  enter the sys.argv 2 is

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? What are you expecting and what do you get?

Comment: Also in your main function, you will get an out of range exception if you pass in less than 2 arguments since you are pulling them before checking the length..

Comment: @Dana i think that's what he's trying to do in `recherche`

Comment: Hi dana, i have added the error i get, this is exactly the out of range exception. I have tried to just write sys.argv2 at the place i needed  instead of calling it in the main and it still didn' work! So instead of the range exeption error i would like to display the error. Like TM adam said, thats what im tryin to do in the elif:

Comment: iv'e added my full code so you can see what's going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
def recherche(essaie):
    while True:
        if len(essaie) > 3:
            print("Un seul argument est attendu, soit le nom du fichier à traiter")
            sys.exit()
        elif len(essaie) < 3:
            print("Il faut préciser le nom du fichier à traiter")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            entree = essaie[1]
            item = essaie[2]
            choix = str(entree)
            texte = choix.strip("[']")

            resultat = [s for s in ligne(texte) if item in s] #finding the word in lines
            resultat2 = str(resultat)
            resultat3 = resultat2.strip("[']")
            print(resultat3)
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recherche(sys.argv)
```

Comment: i dont have to use a main?

Comment: No , it's not c , it's python . You can call your functions wherever you want

Comment: In fact you only have to use `if __name__ == "__main__":` if you plan to import this file to another file , else you can just call `recherche`

Comment: yes thanks its working fine, i would have like to see why it wasn't working with a main hehe but its working really fine.

Comment: You can still use it in `main` if you want , but you don't _have_ to